# How to write an index that I have created to a file in Python

Tags: python, python-2.7

I'm wondering how can I write the following index to a file. The index below is returned from a function that I created.

```
myIndex = {'incorporating': {2047: 1}, 'understand': {2396: 1}, 'format-free': {720: 1}, 'function,': {1579: 1, 485: 1, 831: 1}, '411)': {2173: 1}, 'augmented': {1350: 1}}
```

I want something like this to appear in the output file.

```
'incorporating': {2047: 1} 
'understand': {2396: 1}
'format-free': {720: 1}
'function,': {1579: 1, 485: 1, 831: 1}, '411)': {2173: 1}
'augmented': {1350: 1}
```

This is a code o I have done. I was trying to use writeLine but the output in my file was messed up. So I looked for other methods like pickle.

```
def ToFile(self):
indList = myIndex.constructIndex()  # a function to get the index above
filename = "myfile.txt"
outfile = open(filename, 'wb')
pickle.dump(indexList, outfile)

outfile.close()
```

I have a look in my file but what I got is:

```
ssS'incorporating'
p8317
(dp8318
I2047
I1
ssS'understand'
p8319
(dp8320
I2396
I1
ssS'format-free'
p8321
(dp8322
I720
I1
ssS'function,'
p8323
(dp8324
I1579
I1
sI485
I1
sI831
I1
ssS'411)'
p8325 
(dp8326
I2173
I1
ssS'augmented'
p8327
(dp8328
I1350
I1
ss.
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Pickle is not intended to be nice, but to serialize data to a file such that one can deserialize it efficiently later. Other modules, like the [PrettyPrint](http://docs.python.org/3.3/library/pprint.html?highlight=prettyprint#module-pprint) module are intended to print out Python data in a nice way. If your goal is however to be able to deserialize the data later, you can have a look at the [JSON](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSON) format and its [Python module](http://docs.python.org/3.3/library/json.html?highlight=json#module-json)

```py
>>> import pprint
>>> pp = pprint.PrettyPrinter(indent=4)
>>> pp.pprint(myIndex)
{   '411)': {2173: 1},
    'augmented': {1350: 1},
    'format-free': {720: 1},
    'function,': {485: 1, 831: 1, 1579: 1},
    'incorporating': {2047: 1},
    'understand': {2396: 1}}
>>> import json
>>> output = json.dumps(myIndex,sort_keys=True,indent=4, separators=(',', ': '))
>>> print(output)
{
    "411)": {
        "2173": 1
    },
    "augmented": {
        "1350": 1
    },
    "format-free": {
        "720": 1
    },
    "function,": {
        "485": 1,
        "831": 1,
        "1579": 1
    },
    "incorporating": {
        "2047": 1
    },
    "understand": {
        "2396": 1
    }
}
>>> myRecoveredIndex = json.loads(output)
>>> list(myRecoveredIndex.keys())
['format-free', 'incorporating', 'function,', 'understand', 'augmented', '411)']
>>>
```

If the format you suggested does matter, you can then write the file yourself according to your format. Here is a suggestion of how to do it:

```py
with open("myfile.txt", "w") as fstream:
    for key, data in myIndex.items():
        fstream.write("'{}': {!s}\n".format(key, data))
```

Comment: Does indent=4 means the space in front of the word, for example, XXXX"2173": 1?

Comment: Yes: If indent is a non-negative integer or string, then JSON array elements and object members will be pretty-printed with that indent level. An indent level of 0, negative, or "" will only insert newlines. None (the default) selects the most compact representation. Using a positive integer indent indents that many spaces per level. If indent is a string (such as "\t"), that string is used to indent each level.

Changed in version 3.2: Allow strings for indent in addition to integers. (So indent="\t" will not work for Python 2.7)

Comment: Thank you for your help. I’m appreciated that :)   I have learnt more about PrettyPrinter too.

Answer (score 2):

You should try directly just writing to the file:

```
for key in myIndex:
    outfile.write("'" + key + "': " + str(myIndex[key]) + "\n")
```